# Android WorkManager - get unfinished works from WorkManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

is there any way to get all unfinished works from WorkManager from android-jetpack? I know you can get **Works** by id/tag. But cannot find some way to get all unfinished Works? Thanks for answers :)

Comment: This doesn't look like one of the supported use cases...
Can you expand a bit your question...What are you trying to implement here?

Comment: My usecase is that you must continue you work after all request all done. And do you if in WorkManager is way to call Works in the order in which they were created?

Comment: You can append work in a unique work request, this creates a Chain for you that maintains the order of execution. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. Do you have some examples for working with unique requests in chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is to maintain the order of your work requests, an approach is to use an `UniqueWorkRequest` using as [`ExistingWorkPolicy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#enqueueUniqueWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest)) the `APPEND` one. This creates for you a chain of work:

```
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork("unique name", ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, myOneTimeWorkRequest)
```

You can find more information in [WorkManager's Unique Work guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work). Keep in mind that if you cancel a work request in the chain or return `failure` from your worker, the all chain is cancelled or marked as failed.

Comment: And is there some way to cancel one of the work by tag?

Comment: If we're talking about Workers in a chain (like for a unique work request using the APPEND policy), you can only cancel the whole chain.
In general, as far you have assigned a tag to a work request, you can use `WorkManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(String)`. You can see the doc at:  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . And is there some way, to cancel the Work by tag in chain (i am using unique work with APPEND policy)? My use case is that you have works in chain waiting for network constraint, but in some point I need to cancel one of the work in chain?

Comment: As I wrote, you cannot cancel a single Worker in a chain. You need to handle such situation passing the information that a Worker don't need to run in some other way (maybe setting some flag in your datastore).